# How to use python script to auto login portal?

Tags: python, request, webbrowser-control, urllib3

I have the following code in order to help me auto login the portal but i fond that i able to print the content but the web portal does not pop up :

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
import time
import requests
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
import webbrowser


with requests.Session() as c:
   proxies = {"http://proxy-udd.com"}

   url = 'https://ji.devtools.com/login'
   USERNAME = 'shiji'
   PASSWORD = 'Tan@9'

   c.get(url,verify= False)
   csrftoken = ''

   login_data = dict(proxies,atl_token = csrftoken, os_username=USERNAME, os_password=PASSWORD, next='/')

   c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"referer" : "https://ji.devtools.com/login"})
   page = c.get('https://ji.devtools.com/')
   print (page.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is expected that there is no pop up. You are sending a HTTP request to the portal. The portal did return you the right content as String/Text. However, your python is not a browser. It is not able to process String/Text as browser did. Thus no pop up. If you want to see real pop up with Python, Try selenium. It will try to simulate what browser behaves and you will see a page.

Comment: @VivianTio could you share more details on selenium error? Honestly Selenium is very useful after you completed your initial working trial.

Comment: Yes i try already i successfully get it but only auto fill in password and email but not able log in , this is my post :    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45203176/selenium-with-error-traceback-most-recent-call-last-file-pyshell3-line?noredirect=1#comment77373269_45203176

Answer (score 0):

This is neither written by me nor affiliate to me.
Please use this [link](https://github.com/vdasu/Auto-Login-Script) to follow the full details.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://172.16.16.16/24online/servlet/E24onlineHTTPClient")

username=browser.find_element_by_name("username")
password=browser.find_element_by_name("password")
login=browser.find_eleme

file=open('userid.txt','w')

for i in range(100,200):
    username.send_keys("160905"+i)
    password.send_keys("123456")
    if "You have succesfully logged in" in page.source:
        file.write("160905"+i)
file.close()
browser.close()
```