# Selenium with error Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module> fb_login()

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy-shell

I have the following code that help me auto fill in my data and login:

```
 import webbrowser
 from selenium import webdriver
 import time

 def fb_login():
     br=webdriver.Chrome('C:/Python34/Scripts/chromedriver.exe')
     br.get('https://www.facebook.com/')
     time.sleep(5)
     user=br.find_element_by_css_selector('#email')
     user.send_keys('vivian@hotmail.com')
     password=br.find_element_by_css_selector('#pass')
     password.send_keys('9416@io')
     login=br.find_element_by_css_selector('#u_0_t')
     login.click()
     fb_login()
```

but i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
fb_login()File "C:\Users\SHIJIETI\Desktop\STUPID.py", line 14, in fb_login
login.click()
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 77, in click
self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
return self._parent.execute(command, params)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 256, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
 File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not visible
 (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)
 (Driver info: chromedriver=2.30.477700 (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT 10.0.14393 x86_64)
```

Any one can help me see and check my error?

Comment: What happens if you `print login` before you call `login.click()`?

Comment: Still cannot auto login

Comment: I want to see what it prints.

Comment: Just stop at the login page after auto fill in all the email and detail

Comment: no error found until this stage

Comment: I want you to copy and paste what it printed out onto stack overflow. I don't expect a print statement to solve anything.

Comment: I get this statement:   <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bb5036e001330442a1035fcb423eece1", element="0.598504322827935-3")>
None

Comment: It looks like it's not finding the element you're trying to click on.

Comment: Any idea on this, because this selenium i first time due with it

Comment: You're going to have to look at the HTML that it provides you and see what the CSS selector actually is for the login button.

Comment: yes actually i go to the inspect there and copy the selector

Comment: Try changing the login definition line to this: `login=br.find_element_by_css_selector('#u_0_t')[0]`

Comment: @Cory Madden thank you very much, i found the error already one is the selector you give me, one is replace the click () with submit()

Comment: Awesome. Glad that worked. It looks like it's grabbing 2 different elements, one of which is not visible, and it can't click both. I'm just guessing here, as I haven't used it.